# Disable native JSF implementation of webLogic server and use myfaces implementation

Tags: oracle, jsf, jsf-2, weblogic12c

I've read that Oracle WebLogic Server has an implementation of JSF and it uses it by default. This [article](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/WBAPP/configureresources.htm#WBAPP213) describes the process of disabling this default implementation and allowing the use of different implementations (I want to use myfaces implementation in my case), but i cannot figure out how the weblogic.xml found in my \workspace.metadata is going to look like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90 http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/920/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:jsp-descriptor>
        <wls:keepgenerated>true</wls:keepgenerated>
        <wls:working-dir>D:\Ejada\Eclipse\Mars\Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\base_domain\work\OnlineShop</wls:working-dir>
        <wls:debug>true</wls:debug>
    </wls:jsp-descriptor>
    <wls:context-root>OnlineShop</wls:context-root>
    <wls:weblogic-version>9.2</wls:weblogic-version>
    <prefer-application-packages> 
   <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.sun.faces.*</package-name> 
   <package-name>com.bea.faces.*</package-name> 
   </prefer-application-packages> 

   <prefer-application-resources> 
   <resource-name>javax.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.sun.faces.*</resource-name> 
   <resource-name>com.bea.faces.*</resource-name> 

<resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer</resource-name>
<resource-name>META-INF/services/com.sun.faces.*</resource-name>
   </prefer-application-resources>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

Currently when starting my server it cannot restart with errors:

```
<Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "94264473636217" for task "1" on [partition-name: DOMAIN]. Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101064][WebAppModule(_auto_generated_ear_:OnlineShop)] Error parsing descriptor in Web appplication "D:\Ejada\Eclipse\Mars\Workspace\OnlineShop\WebContent"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND
  <10:7> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app weblogic-version@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app security-role-assignment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app run-as-role-assignment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app resource-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app resource-env-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app ejb-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app service-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app message-destination-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app session-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app jsp-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app auth-filter@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app container-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app async-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app charset-params@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app virtual-directory-mapping@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app url-match-map@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app security-permission@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app context-root@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app wl-dispatch-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app servlet-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app work-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-scheduled-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-thread-factory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app component-factory-class-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app logging@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app library-ref@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app jaspic-provider@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app fast-swap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app coherence-cluster-ref@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app osgi-framework-reference@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app ready-registration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app cdi-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' instead of 'prefer-application-packages@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' here in element weblogic-web-app@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
  <16:6> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.4a: Expected elements 'description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app weblogic-version@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app security-role-assignment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app run-as-role-assignment@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app resource-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app resource-env-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app ejb-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app service-reference-description@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app message-destination-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app session-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app jsp-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app auth-filter@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app container-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app async-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app charset-params@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app virtual-directory-mapping@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app url-match-map@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app security-permission@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app context-root@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app wl-dispatch-policy@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app servlet-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app work-manager@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-scheduled-executor-service@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app managed-thread-factory@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app component-factory-class-name@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app logging@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app library-ref@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app jaspic-provider@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app fast-swap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app coherence-cluster-ref@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app osgi-framework-reference@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app ready-registration@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app cdi-descriptor@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' instead of 'prefer-application-resources@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app' here in element weblogic-web-app@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app
```

What should my weblogic.xml file contain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should contain the following:

```
<container-descriptor>
        <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
        <prefer-application-packages>
            <package-name>javax.faces.*</package-name>
            <package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</package-name>
        </prefer-application-packages>
        <show-archived-real-path-enabled>true</show-archived-real-path-enabled>
    </container-descriptor>
```

Put it in WEB-INF folder.